# Probability of winning/losing

Tags: probability, statistics

Can someone help me with this problem?

**Play roulette 200 times, betting $1 each time.

Option (a): betting on odd or even.

Option (b): betting on a single number.**

**1)    P[win \$40 or more] = 

Which option is better? (a) or (b)? Same?

2)  P[Lose $40 or more] = 

Which option is better (lose less)? (a) or (b)? Same?**

Betting on O/E returns 1:1, but chances of winning is 18/38, so obviously losing is 20/38 (0 and 00 + odd/even)

Betting on single number returns 35:1, winning is 1/38 vs 37/38

So both have an expected value of -2/38

I'm not understand how to come to the probability. I already tried the method with finding the standard deviation, expected value and variance of 200 plays. I got a Z-Score of 31, which is obviously not a Z-Score... So if someone could help it'd be great...

I think I'm going to have to use something with like
$$\sqrt{\frac{qp}{n}}$$

So in my instance is it 
$$\sqrt{\frac{\frac{18}{38} \frac{20}{38}}{200}}$$

Then not sure what to do from there... :/

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As you have found out, $p = \dfrac{18}{38}, q = \dfrac{20}{38}$

$n=200$, and to win \$$40$ or more, you must win at least $120$ times out of $200$

Can you now apply the binomial distribution and find $P(X\ge120)?$

And work out similarly for losing at least \$$40 ?$

---

Using a [binomial calculator](http://vassarstats.net/binomialX.html)
$$P(X\ge120) = \binom{200}{k}\left(\frac{18}{38}^k\right) \left(\frac{20}{38}\right)^{(200-k)} k = 120\; to\; 200 \approx 0.00022 $$

If you are expected to use the normal approximation to the binomial,

mean $= np = 94.68, SD = \sqrt(npq) = 7.061$,

$z-score\;(with\;continuity\;correction) = \frac{(119.5-94.68)}{7.061} = 3.515, P(z>3.515) \approx 0.00022$

You should now be able to  compute losing $\ge \$40$ similarly

Comment: I guess I don't entirely understand the binomial distribution part nor where to go from this... Pretty lost at this point and feel like I've spent way too much time on one problem :/

Comment: It's not a binomial so these don't apply.

Comment: Why is it not binomial ? Can you explain what conditions are lacking ? https://faculty.elgin.edu/dkernler/statistics/ch06/6-2.html